# here my listview is not scrolling dart flutter , please help me iam new to flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scrollview

```
return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     child: Stack(
       children: [
         Positioned(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
           height: 25.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
           child:Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 gradient: LinearGradient(
                     begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                     end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                     colors: [Color(0xff009cba), Color(0xff000e11)])

             ),
             child: Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
               children: [
                 Expanded(flex:3,
                   child: Container(
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                       children: [
                         FittedBox(child: Text("Firm Details",style: GoogleFonts.lato(color: Color(0xfffbfbfb),fontSize: 1.6*SizeConfig.textMultiplier),/*TextStyle(color: Color(0xfffbfbfb),)*/)),
                         SizedBox(height: 0.5*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,),
                         FittedBox(child: Text("Please select the category that best describes your business model.",style: GoogleFonts.lato(color: Color(0xffb3fbfbfb),fontSize: 1.3*SizeConfig.textMultiplier) /*TextStyle(color: Color(0xffb3fbfbfb),fontSize: 12.0)*/,)),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
                 Expanded(flex:1,child:Container(
                   width: 10.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                   height: 10.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                   child:Image.asset("assets/images/firmDetail.png",width:1.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,height: 1.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,),
                 ), ),
               ],
             ),
           ), ),
         Positioned(
           top:20.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
           child:Container(
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
             height: 500.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier),
               color: Colors.white,
             ),
             child:new Container(
               child: ListView(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   SizedBox(height: 2.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,),
                   Center(child: Padding(
                     padding:  EdgeInsets.all(1.8*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                     child: Text("Please select the category that best describes your business model.",style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                   )),
                   horizontalList1,
                   verticalList,    // here vertical list
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   ),
 );
```

here in widget verticallist Listview is not scrolling,but when we add Sizedbox after form with fixedheight then it is scrolling but i dont need fixed height for scrollview

```
      Widget verticalList = new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child:ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child:ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,right: 6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,top:1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,bottom: 1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier),
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'PinCode';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      controller: _pincode,
                      // selectionColor:Color(0xffe4065f),
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 1.6*SizeConfig.textMultiplier,),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "PinCode",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffe4065f)),
                        focusColor: Color(0xffe4065f),
                        hintText:
                        "PinCode",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xffe4065f))),
                      ),
                      //  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,right: 6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,top:1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,bottom: 1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier),
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'PAN of the unit. is required';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _pan,
                      // selectionColor:Color(0xffe4065f),
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 1.6*SizeConfig.textMultiplier,),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "PAN of the unit",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffe4065f)),
                        focusColor: Color(0xffe4065f),
                        hintText:
                        "PAN of the unit",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xffe4065f))),
                      ),
                      //  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,right: 6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,top:1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,bottom: 1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier),
                    child: FormField<String>(
                      builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                        return InputDecorator(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Constitution",
                            errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 1.6*SizeConfig.textMultiplier),
                            hintText: 'Please select expense',),
                          isEmpty: _constitutions == '',
                          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              value: _constitutions,
                              isDense: true,
                              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _constitutions = newValue;
                                  state.didChange(newValue);
                                });
                              },
                              items: _constitution.map((String value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value,
                                  child: Text(value,style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 1.6*SizeConfig.textMultiplier,)),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,right: 6.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,top:1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,bottom: 1.8*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier),
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Line of Activity is required';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _lineActicity,
                      // selectionColor:Color(0xffe4065f),
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 1.6*SizeConfig.textMultiplier,),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Line of Activity",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffe4065f)),
                        focusColor: Color(0xffe4065f),
                        hintText:
                        "Line of Activity",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xffe4065f))),
                      ),
                      //  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 1.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                      right: 1.0*SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
//x                        _postData();
                            if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              //_formKey.currentState.save();
                              if (_constitutions == null || _districtSelectedValue == null) {
                                print("eroore");
                                Flushbar(
                                  message:  "please select required fields",
                                  duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),
                                )..show(context);
                              }  else {
                                // Every of the data in the form are valid at this point
                                _formKey.currentState.save();
                                print(_constitutions);
                              }
                            } else {
                              // submitOtp();
                              _postData();
                            }
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "SAVE & NEXT",
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          color: Color(0xffe4065f),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffe4065f)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
         //   SizedBox(height: 1000,),
          ],
        )
    );
```

here ,when we add Sizedbox after form with fixedheight then it is scrolling but i dont need fixed height for scrollview im new to flutter please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a simple widget hierarchy like

```
Scaffold
 - Container (For the red background)
  - Column
   - Container (with size for the lorem ipsom text.
    - Lorem Ipso Text.
   - Expanded (So that it will use the rest of the height automatically.)
    - Container (with white back ground and top rounded borders. Makes sure you add circular borders only to top and not to bottom of this container.
     - DefaultTabController
      - builder (to get different context of the default tab controller if more than one is used in your full app.)
       - Column
        - TabBar (if the number of categories is large use scrolling here as a property of the tab bar.) wrap in container if you need specific height of the tab bar.
        - Expanded
         - TabBarView to show the appropriate form.
          - SingleChildScrollView
           -Column
            -Your fields
```

Comment: here my second container colour is white with top rounded corners , how can achieve rounded corners without adding a container at the top of another container(red one)

Comment: The first container is for the red color. The third container is for the white with top rounded corners.
When you set the color as red on the first container, the color will be in background.
For the third container you have to use box decoration to set the white background as you need to set the box borders also.

Comment: thanks @Sravan Kumar Nerella , but there is one by changing my keyboard hides actual textfield , is there any way to solve this problem

Comment: What is happening is the top section is not scrollable and it is hiding everything. You can move the single child scroll view to above any of the other column widgets and see which one works for your usecase.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your main widget with the [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) widget

Answer (score 0):

your list view is wrapper in a container that is very long and has no scroll on it. So it wont scroll as the list fits within that long container.
With list views you want a fixed height. It is the fixed height that is given for the visible parts of the list. Remove the wrapping container or reduce the height so all of it is visible on screen.

Also look at your use of the stack. You might have issues once you fix this with the list scrolling on top of the text "Firm Details" etc.

Comment: can  you explain whats the problem with use of stack ,  and also in case of widget vertical list i removed the unwanted height and wrap the widget with listview but still it is not scrolling , i think the problem is on the stack part , thats why it is not scrolling

Comment: What is the usability you are trying to achieve? I am not sure why you have a listview inside a list view? If the usability is complex then you might need a slivers based solution but i am not sure if that is even needed. I was suggesting removing the Container with "height: 500.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier," property.

Comment: when i removing the container "height: 500.0*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier," , it doesnt display the  content inside that container,

Comment: here is the design  i want any idea ? https://imgur.com/a/sRONtI1

Comment: This is a simple design that I belie you ar complicating a lot with stack. See my next answer for better details of a proposed solution.